# 504 Error during the Proxying of Angular with NodeJS inside it

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core

Currently we are trying to run the nodejs server in angular application(net core -angular -spa).We went through this source-
https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/angular-tutorial/what-is-angular-node

As per the project we went on creating the angular application and set the proxy based upon the link : https://angular.io/guide/build#proxy-multiple-entries

The Step we are following this:

#### Step 1: Creation Node Server, which is working individually.

The 504 error shows here.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static("myApp")); // myApp will be the same folder name.


// PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.get('/', (req,res) => {

    res.send('App Works !');

});

app.get('/externalapi/get', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    console.log('App Works !');
    res.send('Got Files!');
    return "Got Files";
  });


app.listen(port, () => {  
    console.log(`Server listening on the port no.:${port}`);

});
```

#### Step 2 : Proxy.config.js **(not json)**

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",     
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  },
  {
    context :[
      "/externalapi/*",
    ],
    target : "http://localhost:8000",
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

#### Step 3: Creation of the Services

```
export class ExampleServices{    
    _nodeUrl : any = '/externalapi/';
    constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient){               
    }


    mergeExamples(files:any) : Observable<any> {
        console.log(this._nodeUrl);
        return this.httpClient.get(this._nodeUrl+"get", files);
    }
}
```

There are two from us ->

1. Why 504 Error occurs in this code ?Is it due to https-> http calling?
   [image]
2. Is there any possibility to run the nodejs command from parent folder itself(currently the externalapi is inside the angular app, have its own node_modules)

Kindly help us with relevant answer and supporting documents.

Comment: Hi All, Got the answer of Why 504 Error occurs in this code ?Is it due to https-> http calling? Need to get information about second question.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).